# adjust aspect ratio of plot in R

Tags: r

I would like to have several subplots in a row in a plot. However the apprearance of each subplot is narrow. How can I adjust the aspect ratio so that each subplot will become wider? Thanks![image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for (i in 1:3){
        dest=density(out[,i])
        hist(out[,i], xlim=range(dest$x),xlab=paste("x[",i,"]"),ylab="density", main="", prob=TRUE)
        lines(dest,col="red")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the device wider (X11, windows, pdf, or whatever is appropriate for your system).

```
 X11(15, 7)
 par(mfrow=c(1,3)) 
 plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
```

etc.

You could also change the margins if you cannot change the device.

```
mar <- par("mar"); mar[c(2, 4)] <- 0
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar = mar) 
plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
plot(density(rnorm(1000)))
```

etc.

Comment: Several OSes allow the user to stretch plotting windows. The plot area is redrawn as a vector object.